# Prevent php from recreating Session array but keep all new values inserted

Tags: php, arrays, session

I have some php code in one php file. I create a session array and initialized it to 0's.

However, I noticed that it is recreating the Session array *every time I hit submit button*. Instead of it retaining inserted values to session array, it recreates the session array which reverts to value of 2 on index 0 instead of replacing it with 4 (2+2).

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['numbers'] = array(2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
?>

<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="index.php"> 
        <label>Enter a number</label>&nbsp;
        <input type="text" name="num" />
         <button type="submit">Submit</button> 
    </form>
</body>
</html>


<?php
     if (isset($_POST["num"]) && !empty($_POST["num"])){

        $userinput = $_POST["num"];

        foreach($_SESSION['numbers'] as $id => $value){

            if(!in_array($userinput, $_SESSION['numbers'])){
                $_SESSION['numbers'][$key] = $userinput; 
            }else{
                $key = array_search($userinput, $_SESSION['numbers']);
                $_SESSION['numbers'][$key] = $userinput + $value; 
                echo $userinput ." is in array";
                break;
            }
        }

    }


        echo "<table border = 1>";
        for($col = 0; $col < sizeof($_SESSION['numbers']); $col++){
            //echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$_SESSION['numbers'][$col]."</td>";
            //echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

        foreach ($_SESSION['numbers'] as $id => $value) {
                echo $value . ", ";
            }   

?>
```

All codes are in one php file.

Thank you.

Comment: You can check if session numbers is [empty](http://php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) before setting it's value.

Comment: @FirstOne Why didn't I thought of that? I want to kick myself. I've just modified my code and it works. Thanks for help.

Comment: @FirstOne Oh no no don't get me wrong. You helped me a lot. I'm coming from Java programming and has limited knowledge with session. I recently just tried out some problems in php. Sorry, I didn't mean for it to sound sarcastic. Peace :)

Answer (score 0):

This is to serve as reference for others who might encounter the same problem. As advised by **FirstOne**, this is what I did.

I modified the part where I declare the session array.

```
<?php 
    session_start();
    if( !isset($_SESSION['numbers']) && !empty($_SESSION['numbers']) ){
        $_SESSION['numbers'] = array(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0);
    }

?>
```

The if condition prevents the Session array from being recreated. In effect, saves or keeps all values submitted when submit button is clicked.

Comment: Note that _empty() does not generate a warning if the variable does not exist. | That means empty() is essentially the concise equivalent to `!isset($var) || $var == false`._ (taken from the docs). This means that you don't _have_ to use `isset`, `empty` alone is enough.